# Автроризация и разделение ролей

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте, помогите реализовать авторизацию пользователей и разделение ролей. Мне главное понять, как это все работает?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) в документации все есть